# When vercel deploying my python app gives Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions

Tags: python, fastapi, vercel, google-cloud-vertex-ai

While installing the web app I prepared using python, vertex ai google chat bison model and fastapi, I constantly get Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions error and the installation does not complete. I also specified the Python version in the Requirements file, but it did not help. I use Vercel with github and all my files are in the root directory. My vercel deployment error screenshot is like this:

[image]

My files are *app.py*, *.env* , *Procfile* , *requirements.txt* and *vercel.json*. The contents of some files are as follows:

**.env file:**

`GOOGLE_API_KEY=MYAPIKEY`

**Procfile:**

`web: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app`

**requirements.txt:**

fastapi==0.110.0

markdown==3.6

python-dotenv==1.0.1

gunicorn==21.2.0

uvicorn==0.29.0

uvicorn-worker==0.1.0

python-multipart==0.0.9

google-generativeai==0.4.1

google-cloud-aiplatform==1.44.0

python==3.9.0

**vercel.json:**

```
{
  "devCommand": "gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app:app",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/app.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/app.py"
    }
  ]
}
```

My project runs very well on my computer in the VsCode environment, but I am having this problem when deploying on Vercel.

I tried editing the `vercel.json` file many times. I updated the versions of the requirements in the `requirements.txt` file, i set the python version to `3.9.0` which is supported by vercel at requirements file but it did not solve my problem. I would be very happy if you could help me with what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue just now, resolved it by downgrading the Node.js version from 20.x to 18.x in Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a thread about the same issue on vercel's github.
In my case, even downgrading to node 18.x, the building error persists as `"Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions"`.

This has never happened before
using vercel’s own templates

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/6287